# directive not showing scope in template

Tags: angularjs

something simple im sure..
ive set up a very simple directive that accepts an isolated scope item

the template simply prints out the name.

```
  .directive('createDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<div>{{name}} - 123</div>',
          scope: { name:'&myName'}
      }
  });
```

the HTML:-

```
 <create-directive my-name="bob" ></create-directive>
```

however,  its failing to print out 'bob'
im failing to see why not?

Answer (score 1):

[Scope configuration](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) is incorrect. It should be:

```
scope: {
    name: '@myName'
}
```

Special character `&` is used to setup a function reference to the outer scope function.